# Add android support library v4 to intellij ide

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-support-library

I am trying to use viewpager from android support library v4 in intelli j. Currently, I am using the Android SDK 4.1

I copied `android-support-v4.jar` to my intellij android project under 'libs'

in the project settings of intellij

I went to **"Modules" => "MyModuleName" => dependencies** tab, and add the android-support-v4.jar, by navigating the path to the libs/ folder under my own project

I checked the 'export' besides this newly added jar file

but I still can't use viewpager in my application.

I get a crash msg like:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxx/com.xxxx.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

Comment: Library should be loaded with this configuration, the problem is elsewhere. It's hard to tell where exactly without a sample to reproduce.

Comment: if i send u the exported project file would that help ? from intellij that is

Comment: Zip and share the project directory.

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply...i got work...i have sent it to ur gmail..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've inspected the project you provided and found the problem to be caused by the **incorrect library configuration**. When adding a library, you've specified `android` folder inside the `jar` instead of specifying the `jar` itself.

Incorrect configuration:

[image: incorrect]

Correct configuration:

[image: correct]

Comment: thank you crazycoder...sorry for such silly mistake and i appreciate your professionalism to help me on this on stackoverflow as well as spending your time taking a look at my project.  Bravo CrazyCoder!